# Using same XSLT key with different contexts subsequently. Semantics depends on XSLT version or XSLT engine?

Tags: xslt, key, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

With this example:

[XSLT Keys Example](http://xsltransform.net/gVTZeUx)

I got different results by only changing the XSLT version from 1.0 to 2.0.

With v1.0 result is: `<result>111</result>` (obviously the key is initialized with the context when is used the first time and stays unchanged). But with v2.0. result is: `<result>1 61 61 6</result>` there it seems the key is reinitialized whenever the context changes.

My question is if this is because of different XSLT version 1.0 vs 2.0 semantics or can it also be caused by different XSLT engines and same XSLT version? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of `xsl:value-of` has changed in XSLT 2; while in [XSLT 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#value-of) `<xsl:value-of select="some-expression"/>` outputs a text node with the string value of the first node selected by `some-expression` in [XSLT 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#value-of) a text node containing a space separated (more generally, the value of the `separator` attribute if present) sequence of the string values of all selected items is created.

XSLT 2 or 3 processors supporting [XPath 1 backwards compatibility mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-backwards-compatible-behavior) will use the XSLT 1 behaviour where `xsl:version="1.0"` or `version="1.0"` is used.